# The weapon is not colliding with the AI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        Debug.Log(collider.gameObject.tag);
    }
```

When it collides with the weapon (or anything) it should print the tag. The problem is that it doesn't print anything.
[image]

Here you can see the player (normal colours) hitting the AI (green) and I am 100% that the AI is within the bounds of the weapons hitbox.

[image]

The AI layer and the player layers do interact with each other.
[image]

This is the box collider on the weapon (ignore it being disabled)

[image]

This is the box collider on the AI.
I have tried using `ontriggerenter2D`, `ontriggerstay2D`, `ontriggerexit2D`, `ontriggerenter`, `ontriggerstay`, `ontriggerexit`, `oncollisionexit`, `oncollisionstay`. I honestly have no clue why it is like this.

I know that it is not entering the on collision enter because it should be printing the ground tag that I have on the ground. Also the game is in 2D.

Comment: Why is the one collider disabled?

Comment: @derHugo It gets enabled in the animations

Comment: I see .. so you move things by animator .. are both Rigidbody kinematic then?

Comment: No they are dynamic

Comment: Is the collider on the same object as the script?

Comment: The collider is not on the same object as the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the rigidbody or the collider have to be on the same game object as the script for the collision/trigger enter and exit methods to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

- The OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) is on a script that
  inherits from MonoBehaviour
- This same MonoBehaviour script is in one of the GameObjects (Player
  or AI)
- This script is attached to a GameObject that also has a Collider2D
  component

Last but not least...

- ***Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody2D attached*** **to it's GameObject** as you can read it on the [MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)